# Select/Deselect All Checkboxes along with colour changing of a selected row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selectall

I have a table where each row has some data and the user can submit all rows or single row or some rows. So, every row has a checkbox now and If the user checks the checkbox the background colour of this row should be changed(I have implemented this using jquery). Now there is another checkbox to select All these checkboxes, I have implemented this too with jquery. Now the issue is that when I selectAll checkboxes the row background-colour doesnot change , but when I check individual rows it gets changed. Being a novice coder I can understand that click event is not happening so the background colour is not changing. So I have used change event instead of click , but it's still the same. The functions for select All and row background colour change are working good but individually. Need help regarding this...

Thanks in advance,
NoviceCoder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any of your code I tried something. See if you can apply to your code. ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/yDyAj/3/))

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAll" /></th>
            <th>Row name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" /></td>
            <td>test row 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" /></td>
            <td>test row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" /></td>
            <td>test row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" /></td>
            <td>test row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" /></td>
            <td>test row 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected { background-color: #ffff00; }
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('tbody :checkbox').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
    });
    $('thead :checkbox').change(function() {
        $('tbody :checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Comment: `toggleClass(className, switch)` has a second argument called switch that could reduce a part of the script to just `$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);`. Nice example though!!

Comment: You could also shorten the other event handler function to `$('tbody :checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');`. :)

Comment: I thougt, if I use simplified version, when `selectAll` clicked it may  trigger already selected checkboxes and occur remove class. I tried after your suggestion and it works well. So another update is coming up. Thanks again. :)

Comment: First of all, pardon me for not writing the code. Thank you for providing the code by taking pain in reading all those lines out there :) . Actually, the line containing .prop gave error to me, though I have changed it to .attr and got it :) Anyhow a simple toggle class would not be much helpful in my case as the rows (which are dynamically obtained) have different background colours for even and odd rows. I must have missed out that in question :|..

Comment: One more thing, when I check selectall and uncheck any one row then the selectall checkbox should be unchecked which doesnot happen here.  I'm glad for your responses: Emre Erkan and @Stefan

Comment: `        var allChecked = $('tbody :checkbox:checked').length == $('tbody :checkbox').length;
        $('thead :checkbox').prop('checked', allChecked );` See http://jsfiddle.net/yDyAj/4/

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example for your request just copy/paste all this code, in new page and run it. Enjoy

```
<html>
<head>
<title>How to highlight the selected row in table/gridview using jquery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#checkall").live('click',function(event){
$('input:checkbox:not(#checkall)').attr('checked',this.checked);
//To Highlight
if ($(this).attr("checked") == true)
{
//$(this).parents('table:eq(0)').find('tr:not(#chkrow)').css("background-color","#FF3700");
$("#tblDisplay").find('tr:not(#chkrow)').css("background-color","#FC9A01");
}
else
{
//$(this).parents('table:eq(0)').find('tr:not(#chkrow)').css("background-color","#fff");
$("#tblDisplay").find('tr:not(#chkrow)').css("background-color","#FFF");
}
});
$('input:checkbox:not(#checkall)').live('click',function(event)
{
if($("#checkall").attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
{
$("#checkall").attr('checked',false);
$(this).closest('tr').css("background-color","#ffffff");
}
if(this.checked == true)
{
$(this).closest('tr').css("background-color","#FC9A01");
CheckSelectAll();
}
if(this.checked == false)
{
$(this).closest('tr').css("background-color","#ffffff");
}
});

function CheckSelectAll()
{
var flag = true;
$('input:checkbox:not(#checkall)').each(function() {
if(this.checked == false)
flag = false;
});
$("#checkall").attr('checked',flag);
}
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="50%" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" id="tblDisplay" cellpading="0"
style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px;">
<thead>
<tr id="chkrow">
<th>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
</th>
<th>
Sr.
</th>
<th style="text-align: left;">
First Name
</th>
<th style="text-align: left;">
Last Name
</th>
<th>
Country
</th>
<th>
Marital Status
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
1
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Adeel
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Fakhar
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Pakistan
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Single
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
2
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Omer
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Fakhar
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Pakistan
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Single
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
3
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Umer
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Mukhtar
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Pakistan
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Single
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
4
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Mark
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
Waugh
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Australia
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
Married
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx a ton kaissun, I actually missed out mentioning that even and odd rows have different background colours(I felt this a bit complex). The checkbox id's would be like checkbox1, checkbox2..so on..What i did earlier is extracted the checkbox id and used substr to get last letter and applied modulus to it for even or odd, but integrating this logic into your code is not that easy for me. It would be helpful If you could get me through this. Anyhow, I'm glad for your response. :)